# Screen size anomaly

Tags: android, screen-size

```
density = 1.0
densityDpi = 160
heightPixels = 552
noncompatDensity = 1.0
noncompatHeightPixels = 552
noncompatWidthPixels = 1024
scaledDensity = 1.0
widthPixels = 1024
xdpi = 168.89351
ydpi = 169.33333
```

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0, with the specs above. If I understand correctly, the smallest width of the device is 552 dp. (SW=widthPixels*160/densityDpi) My app runs on this device, despite of the android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" line in the manifest. Why is this possible? How can I get the real SmallestWidthDp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My app runs on this device, despite of the android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" line in the manifest. Why is this possible? How can I get the real SmallestWidthDp?

Although the resolution of this device is 1024x600 and the smallest width is thus probably 600dp, the `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp` attribute wouldn't prevent your device from running the app as mentioned in the [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#requiresSmallest):

> **Caution:** The Android system does not pay attention to this attribute, so it does not affect how your application behaves at runtime. [...]